# Set NSHTTPCookieExpires manually

Tags: ios, objective-c, nshttpcookie

I want to set a `NSHTTPCookie` in the `NSHTTPCookieStorage`.

For doing that, I am creating a cookie & adding it to the `NSHTTPCookieStorage` as shown below:-

```
NSDictionary  *propertiesDevice = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"http://www.sample.com/", NSHTTPCookieDomain,
                                   @"/", NSHTTPCookiePath,
                                   @"someCookieName", NSHTTPCookieName,
                                   @"myCookieValue", NSHTTPCookieValue,
                                   timeStamp,NSHTTPCookieExpires,nil];
NSHTTPCookie *cookieDevice = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:propertiesDevice];
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]setCookie:cookieDevice];
```

All the properties of the `NSHTTPCookie` sets as expected, apart from the `NSHTTPCookieExpires`.

1. If I pass `[NSDate date]`, then the value is set. But the problem is it is not in the desired `NSHTTPCookie` format of `Expires=Tue, 15-Jan-2013 21:47:38 GMT`. The format of `[NSDate date]` is `2014-06-19 12:04:00 +0000`.
2. When I try to change the format of `NSDate` using `NSDateFormatter`, the output is `NSString`.
3. The problem is that no matter what `NSString` I set to `NSHTTPCookieExpires` key, it takes `null` value.

Though in the documentation it says that `NSHTTPCookieExpires` takes `NSString` or `NSDate`.

```
    From Apple Doc:-

    <td>NSHTTPCookieExpires</td>
    <td>NSDate or NSString</td>
    <td>NO</td>
    <td>Expiration date for the cookie. Used only for version 0
    cookies. Ignored for version 1 or greater.</td>
```

Does anyone have any idea as to why we are not able to set `NSString` value for the key `NSHTTPCookieExpires`?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it wasn't working because I was cloning an existing cookie and `NSHTTPCookieDiscard` was defined there.

Removing it solved the problem.

There are other rules that can make the expiration date `nil`, even if you set it with a valid `NSDate` or `NSString`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookie_Class/